# How to Change A button on Visual Composer at Onchange Event in at the time of user option change(Select option)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to Change the Button that are come from plugin to on my visual composer. 
Here is My code

[`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/L5dmkj7s/)

I want to change price on change event

The Visual Composer doesn't allow to Jquery, Javascript, Ajax in Source Code. Can I do this activity on Visual browser

Site Link
http://demourls.org/newdemo/imarket/package/

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no restrictions to use javascript, You can add them in raw_js block.

For your template you just need to add wrapper for that button (or any other better type to get button selector)

```
<div class="wrapper-for-click">
[wp_cart_button name="Test Product" price="149.99"]
</div>
```

And then you can use any native js/jquery solutions like:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.wrapper-for-click button', function(e){
   console.log('button inside .wrapper clicked!');
});
```